# Convert from TypeScript Definition file to TypeScript or JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there any way to convert a TypeScript definition file to a JavaScript file/TypeScript file. I understand that the TypeScript definition file only has the definitions, not the implementations.  I'm fine with generating empty functions and undefined variables.

I am unable to find a way do this though.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to replace `declare` with `` and `;` with `{}` ... I think. But there is almost definitely no tool to do this already.

You are mostly better off starting a new TypeScript API since JavaScript libs aren't exactly *type* friendly by default.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will have to write my own for this special "circumstance".